# Does using Xapian in Django-Haystack enforces GPL?

Tags: licensing, gpl, bsd-license

Consider the following situation:

- She uses [Django](https://www.djangoproject.com/) (BSD) for a website.
- She uses [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/) (BSD) for textual search in the website.
- She uses the backend of haystack, [xapian-haystack](https://github.com/notanumber/xapian-haystack) (GPL), to use [Xapian](http://xapian.org/) (GPL) as the search engine of Haystack.

Question: must she distribute the source code of her website under GPL (or equivalent)?

My question is specific on whether the source code is considered to be a derivative GPL code.

Pragmatically, I would say the code is written entirely in Python+Django+Haystack, and Xapian could be substituted by other search engine. Indeed, the difference in the code is as simple as

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.xapian_backend.XapianEngine',
        'PATH': os.path.join('tmp', 'test_xapian_query'),
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    }
}
```

or

```
HAYSTACK_CONNECTIONS = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'haystack.backends.elasticsearch_backend.ElasticsearchSearchEngine',
        'URL': 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/',
        'INDEX_NAME': 'test_default',
        'INCLUDE_SPELLING': True,
    },
}
```

But I would like very much to have a second opinion on this.